# Is it bad practice to redeclare slices in every loop iteration?

Tags: go

As an example:

```
for {
    myData := <-myChan
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    encoder := gob.NewEncoder(buf)
    err := encoder.Encode(myData)
    ...
```

I could put `buf := new(...` above the for loop to save processor and maybe some memory, but will that cause any problems?  Examples I see have the `new` in the loop.

Edit: for the case above, the encoder could go above the for loop to, so why doesn't it (in examples I've seen)?

Comment: If you're creating DB connections, http clients etc. - things that as considered expensive operations - these should be done ahead of time, outside of a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic Go style would be to write the clearest code possible as long as it solves the problem at hand within its time and space constraints.

In other words, I wouldn't worry about the efficiency here because:

1. The compiler can do clever optimizations that would remove any differences
2. Almost certainly if there are differences, they are negligible

---

If you find out that the allocation takes a considerable portion of each loop iteration, then @peterSO's answer below is a good pattern on how to reuse a `bytes.Buffer` by calling its `Reset` method.

Comment: " I wouldn't worry about the efficiency here ". I would.

Comment: @peterSO: I'd be happy to see realistic benchmarks where allocating one struct with a couple of fields would make a difference, particularly in cases where each iteration of the same loops reads from a channel and encodes data

Comment: @EliBendersky Reusing the allocation for [Buffer.buf](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/170b8b4b12be50eeccbcdadb8523fb4fc670ca72/src/bytes/buffer.go#L21) may be beneficial depending on the the size and distribution of the encoded values.

Answer (score 7):

I would expect to reuse the buffer:

```
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
for {
    buf.Reset()
    //...
}
```